# How to open a csv file from Excel with a particular line highlighted?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vbscript

I have a large `CSV` file and I want to programmatically open it in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) with a particular line highlighted (I know the line number). What is the easiest way to this?

I think my options are:

1. Auto convert the csv file to an xlsx file. How can I do this from a script?
2. Give Excel some arguments when it opens up. No idea what command line arguments Microsoft products take.
3. Somehow interact with Excel after it opens up the CSV file and tell it to highlight a particular. Again not sure how.

I prefer Java/Python/Shell or anything that would work across Mac/Windows assuming the system has Excel installed. So, my best bet is probably `#1` which brings me back to the question how can I convert a `CSV` file to a `xlsx` file.

Comment: Programmatically using what?  The most straightforward answer to your question will depend on that to some extent.

Comment: I note that the initial question I answered did not reference the Mac (hence I didn't address this point). As I do not have a Mac I can't assist further.  Good luck with the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works simple save it in an empty workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbooks.Open ("test.csv")
    Range("8:8").Select
End Sub
```

also if you save that in your normal.dot (the default template document when opening excel) it will run on any document it opens. so what you could do is:

save this to your normal.dot

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Range("8:8").Select
End Sub
```

then change the default application for opening .csv files to excel. then whenever you double-click on .csv file it will be opened with excel and excel will run the Workbook_Open() sub and viola!

Comment: So I created an empty file and wrote your first suggestion into it and created a sample test.csv in the same directory and saved that file (the file with your script) as .xlsb file (Excel workbook) and it said Excel could not open that .xlsb file. I am confused. I am looking at your first block of code - do I run it somehow or do I save it into a file that I open in Excel?

Comment: are you using excel for MAC? if so you can go to (Menu) Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor > Double Click on "ThisWorkbook" you should get a window that has two drop down lists, in the one on the left that says general declarations click the down arrow and select workbook. the one on the right should change to open, place the code I wrote there and save the workbook.

Comment: Cool that works! But I want to do this "programmatically" i.e. generate a file given a csv file and a line number that if my client clicks on their vanilla machine would open in Excel on Mac/Windows provided they have Excel installed as default app for certain common file types in their system with that line highlighted.

Comment: well, you could save that script I gave you into a file called normal.dot and then distribute that normal.dot to your clients. it has to be placed in a specific place on each machine. I.E. (on windows) %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm and on OSX ~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/Normal.dotm

Comment: you would need to use the second script. the one that does not look for a csv file. do the same as before tools macro vb ... and save it as normal.dotm in one of those two locations depending on the os.

Answer (score 8):

You could run a basic [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) which avoids the need to have Excel already open, and conversion isn't necessary.

1. Paste the code below into a text editor `NotePad`
2. Change the path to your CSV file to suit (ie *"c:\temp\test2.csv"*)
3. Save the file as something like `MyCSV.vbs` say to your Desktop

Click on the final [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) to open the CSV file to Row X (8 in the sample below)

```
Dim objExcel
Dim WB
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\test2.csv")
With objExcel
.Goto WB.Sheets(1).Rows(8)
.Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: +1 Excel is more than capable with csv files so as brettdj says no need to convert to xlsx

Comment: What about Macs (with Excel on it)? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: +1  You could even pass the filename and row number to the script as command line parameters

Comment: @wrick, on a Mac you can have a loader.xlsx with this code on it

Comment: I didn't think certain versions oc MAC Excel can run VBA. perhaps I'm wrong. This is likely why the OP asked for java / python possible solutions. (added tags)

Comment: Office 2004 and 2011 have VBA compatability, mostly. 2004 should be compatable, but there was some properties and events left out in 2011 that you'll need to check your code against what MS says was not implemented.